# Identify keyboard

Tags: keyboard, hardware

I have two keyboards connected to my PC, is there any way to know what keyboard a key was pressed on in any language or framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Windows, you can register you application to receive [raw input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645536(VS.85).aspx) notifications with the [RegisterRawInputDevices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645600(VS.85).aspx) API. Once you register, your application will start receiving [WM_INPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645590(VS.85).aspx) messages. The lParam to that message is a pointer to a [RAWINPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645562(VS.85).aspx) structure. You can use the [GetRawInputData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645596(VS.85).aspx) API to get the header in the form of [RAWINPUTHEADER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645571(VS.85).aspx) structure. Then you can use the [GetRawInputDeviceInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645597(VS.85).aspx) on the device handle from the header to extract information for the device that generated the input.

I am not aware of other ways to get the device that generated the keyboard input on Windows.

I also have no idea how to address that problem on any other operating systems.

Comment: Thank you! GetRawInputData is above bellow or at tehe same level with DirectInput from DirectX?

Comment: Does anyone know the solution on linux for this? It'd be interesting to know. :)

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure how raw input relates to DirectInput.